# Problem in Google Visualization Chart Api

Tags: html, gwt, charts, google-api, google-visualization

I am using GWT

If You look at my code ,  When I click on Hide button it clear the pieFlowPanel Panel but when I click on Show button it does not show my PieChart

final Panel panel = RootPanel.get();
        final FlowPanel pieFlowPanel = new FlowPanel();

```
    final Runnable onLoadCallback = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            PieChart pie;
            // Create a pie chart visualization.
            pie = new PieChart(createTable(), createOptions());
            pie.addOnMouseOverHandler(createSelectHandler(pie));
            //                pie.addSelectHandler(createSelectHandler(pie));
            pieFlowPanel.add(pie);
            panel.add(pieFlowPanel);
        }
    };
    VisualizationUtils.loadVisualizationApi(onLoadCallback, PieChart.PACKAGE);
    Button button = new Button("Hide");
    Button button2 = new Button("Show");

    button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            pieFlowPanel.clear();

        }
    });

    button2.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            final Runnable onLoadCallback1 = new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    Window.alert("RUN");
                    PieChart pie;
                    pie = new PieChart(createTable(), createOptions());
                    pie.addOnMouseOverHandler(createSelectHandler(pie));
                    pieFlowPanel.add(pie);
                    panel.add(pieFlowPanel);
                }
            };
            VisualizationUtils.loadVisualizationApi(onLoadCallback1, PieChart.PACKAGE);
        }
    });

    panel.add(button);
    panel.add(button2);
```

Please suggest me solution ...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem earlier. All my applications that use a customized component based on Visualization API suddenly stop working, even older versions and local deployments.

Then I replace this line:

```
VisualizationUtils.loadVisualizationApi(onLoadCallback, Blabla.PACKAGE);
```

with:

```
VisualizationUtils.loadVisualizationApi(onLoadCallback);
```

and it works. Still have no idea on what has happened though.